# Empty `include_path` in PHP default

Tags: php, include

If I have an empty `include_path` in PHP (like `include_path=:`), my `include` and `require` functions still work. It is like `include` tries the initial script's directory first, regardless of what your `include_path` is set to.

This gets more confusing to me when I set the `include_path` to something like `/usr/lib/php5/`, and then try to `include('test.php')` from a script that has no `test.php` in the same directory. I would imagine it would look for `test.php` in my specified `include_path` if it wasn't present in the current directory.

I am not looking for a solution; I can already solve my current problem. I am looking for an explanation as to how `include_path` works. Thanks!

Comment: A simple RTFM would get you your answer: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: yes, but that does not explain the examples i have given.

Comment: great, thanks for the link. i looked all around but the one thing i didnt check was the include/require documentation (because i was looking for the include_path explantion). im not sure why you feel the need to insult me when i made an honest mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically if you just speicfy the name of the file to be included without any path info then then include_path will be used.

i.e.

```
include 'wow.php';  (this will use include_path to try to find it)
```

if it cant find it then it will look in the same directory as the file that tried to include it.

```
include '/blah/wow.php';
```

because this has some path info in it then it will ignore include_path all together.

Comment: excellent explanation, but i think it will look directory of the initial script, not the script that included it (in the case you had nested includes), right?

Comment: actually, i just tested this and it seems to check the current scripts directory first, and then check the initial scripts directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.php');
```